# How do I use the "runas" command to open an application, on the same pinned icon, on Windows 10 PRO?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10, taskbar, runas

I'm trying to run an application with **another user** on windows 10, that application is **pinned** on taskbar.

1- If I use **"shift + right button"** and select **"Run as different user"** the application will open in the same pinned icon.

2- But I want to use the command **"runas"**, because I can save the credentials, and if I use this command, the **application opens in another icon in the taskbar**!

How do I use the "runas" command to open an application, **on the same pinned icon**?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Does it occur with any application or may it be that it only appears if you run PowerShell as another user?

Comment: Ow sorry, yes, aplicattion is NetBeans 8.2 runing over java 1.8.0_271 64bit and windows 10 64bit. with powershell this does not happen !!!!

Comment: See this video !!! https://youtu.be/8E1fzYny9hI